# ASCII Control characters: \x0e - \x1f

Tags: python-2.7

I want to convert the \x0e and \x0f characters to equivalent keyboard text.

Does python able to encode/decode the ASCII control characters(\x0e - \x1f) to keyboard text.

Comment: Which keyboard text are you talking about?

Comment: I want to convert the \x0e value to equivalent text values.

Comment: That already is the text value.

Comment: Great.. Thanks, Can we convert it to any alphabet or number values?

Comment: Yes. Are there any particular characters you would like them to be.

Comment: Not a particular character. I want to convert its equivalent values

Comment: Still not clear what you mean, do you want to receive ASCII symbol like SO for \x0e? Could you please let an example?

Comment: Can we convert the \X0e to its equivalent symbol value

Comment: For \x0e the ASCII symbol is "SO". Is it what you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

This is not encoded (well not in ascii anyway).  This is how the text *is supposed to look*.

ascii is encoded something like `\55` (which is a "-") and nothing like you have given above.

Proof of this can be found if we run your commands and then `\55` through this simple program I built:

```
text = "\x0e \x0f \55" # What we want to try goes here
new_text = text.encode('ascii') # What we want to encode it in
print new_text  # Print the outcome
```

The outcome is:

> \x0e \x0f -

This shows that `\55` has been converted and so has `\x0e` `\x0f` however they remain the same because they are not encoded in ascii.